# Is there a internal url for the File API - Directories and Filesystem on Chrome similar to chrome://appcache-interanals for appcache?

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I have been playing with HTML5 Offline web apps and the File API using Chrome. After looking at what the guys and girls have done at [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), 
I was wondering if there is a way to find out more information about the file system/sandbox?

For example: 
 - Where on disk is the files/sandbox being stored?
 - How much space is free/used?
 - Is the data encrypted?

I am hoping for an internal Chrome url similar to chrome://appcache-internals which allows you to manage the appcache for an offline web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks the the book [Using Html5 Filesystem API](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021360.do) (by Eric Bidelman), if you go to "chrome://settings/cookies" search for your url you can find quota and usage stats about the local filesystem.

The following code snippet also prints out this info:

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota(TEMPORARY, function(usage, quota) {
        console.log('Using: ' + (usage / quota) * 100 + '% of temporary storage');}, 
    function(e) { 
        console.log('Error', e); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

chrome://quota-internals is the file API (as well as a few other bits and pieces) analog to chrome://appcache-internals. In fact, since appcache is quota-managed in Chrome, I imagine that appcache-internals will go away at some point in the future, replaced entirely by a quota management page.

It appears to be broken in the current dev channel release, but it's working in tip-of-tree, so I'm sure it'll be available again soon. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just gave it a go and you are right it seems to be broken. I will keep an eye on it and when the next version of chrome trickles down I give it another go, thanks again.